oAuth - refresh token flow
I am trying to get a new access token via the refresh token when the current access token has expired:
auth_url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token'

payload = {
    "grant_type": "refresh_token",
    "refresh_token": "...",
    "client_id": "...",
    "client_secret": "..."
}

response = requests.post(auth_url, data=payload) # {'error': 'invalid_client_id', 'error_description': 'client identifier invalid'}

Note:
I got the refresh token by the following requests:

Retrieved authorization code
"https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&scope=refresh_token"

Exchanged authorization code for access and refresh tokens:
uri_token_request = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token'

token = requests.post(uri_token_request, data={
 'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
 'code': authorization_code,
 'client_id': '...',
 'client_secret': '...',
 'redirect_uri': redirect_uri}).json()



Connect App Configuration:




On the face of it, this looks correct. What happens if you send client id/secret in Authorization header instead of body?
